# Unexpected behaviour of for_each with transform

Tags: c++

When I uncomment the commented line with std::transform then the above for_each won't print anything. The for_each below also does not print anything. I thought the code would take the elements from v, increase them and insert them into v2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print(const int& what){
    cout<<what<<" ";
}

int change(const int& from){
    return from+1;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v(5,10);
    vector<int> v2;

    for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),print);
    //transform(v.begin(),v.end(),v2.begin(),change);
    for_each(v2.begin(),v2.end(),print);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first `for_each` prints 10 five times, regardless whether you uncomment `transform` or not.

Comment: @jrok I don't think you understood the question he asked why the second for_each prints nothing if he doesn't call transform

Comment: @aaronman I did understand. It's just that Q says different things than code actualy does. Well, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: My C++ is rusty, but shouldn't you be wrapping v2 with a `std::back_inserter` inside the `transform` call, instead of passing `v2.begin()`? i.e. `transform(v.begin(),v.end(), std::back_inserter(v2),change);`

Comment: @aaronman Actually, I asked why the FIRST for_each does not print anything when the transform line is uncommented.

Comment: @jrok yeah I messed up, I didn't even bother running the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second collection is empty -- to insert items into it, you'd want to use a std;:back_inserter:

```
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(v2), change);
```

Note, however, that `for_each` isn't really the optimal choice here either. If you're going to use a standard algorithm, I'd recommend copying to an `ostream_iterator`:

```
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(v2));
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

If all you really want to do is add one to each item in the input, you may find it easier to use something like `std::plus` instead of writing that code for yourself (or, if you have C++11 available, you could use a lambda).

To answer the question you actually asked (why none of it really works when you do your `transform` as it was): you had undefined behavior attempting to access the vector outside its current bounds. As such, any behavior is allowed. It's often a little hard to see how UB *later* in a program could affect behavior of code before the UB has actually been invoked, but the standard is quite explicit in allowing that. Some compilers take advantage of this to enable optimizations (for example) that wouldn't be (or might not be) possible otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I just wonder why is for_each not an optimal choice here.

Comment: @Slazer: Two points: first, `for_each` just does something arbitrary to every item in a range -- it's preferable to use a more specialized algorithm when possible. Second, it requires that you break the functionality up into separate "pieces", so you need to look in a couple of different places to get any idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

The destination range for `std::transform` must be large enough to hold the results. Your `v2` is an empty vector. You could call `v2.resize()` before calling `std::transform` or use `back_inserter` like so:

```
transform(v.begin(),v.end(),back_inserter(v2),change);
```